# Selenium xPath - Locating element by partial text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I have following HTML code of my Page.

```
<div class="views-field-wbapi-data-value-2014 wbapi-data-value wbapi-data-value-first">
    <span class="field-content">
        <span>
            <a href="http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL/countries/SC?display=graph">
                <span class="human-readable"></span>
            </a>
```

And

```
<div class="views-field-wbapi-data-value-2014 wbapi-data-value wbapi-data-value-first">
    <span class="field-content">
        <span>
            <a href="http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD/countries/SC?display=graph">
                <span class="human-readable">91,400</span>
            </a>
```

I have come up with the following xpath to locate `<span class="human-readable"></span>` of the first HTML code block.

```
//div[@class='views-field-wbapi-data-value-2014 wbapi-data-value wbapi-data-value-first']/span/span/a/span
```

But when I run the above xpath, it gives me 2 matching nodes which is clear to me from the HTML code. There is a slight difference in href parameter of tag 'a'. The first code block contains "SP.POP.TOTL" and the second block contains "NY.GDP.MKTP.CD".

Is there any way I can access partial text of href parameter of 'a' tag and use it in my xpath to differentiate between the 2 blocks?

**Note: I cannot use the following xpath:
`//a[@href='http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL/countries/SC?display=graph']/span` because I am running a for loop on 40 different countries and every time text after '/countries/' , "SC" , changes. So I have to use partial text , independent of the country prefix.**

Comment: i am just in my pc...and working on your yesterday question...hope u will get it soon

Comment: //div[@class='views-field-wbapi-data-value-2014 wbapi-data-value wbapi-data-value-first']/span/span/a/span[0]
  
//div[@class='views-field-wbapi-data-value-2014 wbapi-data-value wbapi-data-value-first']/span/span/a/span[1]

Answer (score 4):

use this as cssSelector:

```
a[href*='SP.POP.TOTL']>span.human-readable
```

use this in code like below:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='SP.POP.TOTL']>span.human-readable"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the contains function?
You could try adding the following.

```
/a[contains(@href,'SP.POP.TOTL')]/span
```